# What does "dispatch()" mean/do, and why is it used when we have .then() and .catch()

Tags: node.js, axios, dispatch

I am new to ES6 and advanced javascript. I have seen examples of code using the axios http client like this:

```
axios.xxx(...).then((res) => dispatch(success(res)) , (err)=> dispatch(error(err)))
```

whereas I am doing:

```
axios.xxx(...).then(function(res){...}).catch(function(err){...});
```

I tried to look up dispatch on MDN but only found DispatchEvent... which is not the same? I ask because although my code works, I am finding http error codes like 403 etc from my api are handled as errors by axios, while i would prefer to handle them myself in the app. (Update: when I added the dispatch tag to this question, I saw a brief summary of the meaning but I am still confused).

**What is the reason or advantage for using dispatch? Is "dispatch()" part of axios, or ES6, or nodejs?** thx.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When I see `dispatch` I immediately think of [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) (a popular middleware for [Redux](http://redux.js.org/)). It is a good example of why passing `dispatch` is useful. Basically `dispatch` is used as a callback which gets invoked once some async action is complete. In redux-thunk `dispatch` is simply a function which dispatches an action to the Redux store after, let's say, you fetch data from an API (which is asynchronous). You can pass any function you like to `.then()` or `.catch()` of some Promise and it will be invoked upon success or failure.

Comment: thank you for this info... but i think it doesn't really answers the question.

Comment: What do you need to know exactly?

Comment: per my question itself: **(1) Is "dispatch()" part of axios, or ES6, or nodejs?** and **(2) why would you use dispatch instead of .then() and .catch()**?

Comment: As I said, dispatch is probably a function provided by a library. Can you tell us where you saw it?

Comment: Oh I see... I saw references to dispatch when I was trying to debug my code which uses axios... and then several browser tabs later, I ended up here: https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/770914221638942720?lang=en ... I've lost the trail of how I got there. So I guess this is specific to redux and I don't need to worry about this if I'm not using redux? I'm only using plain react.

Comment: Absolutely, just carry on :)