# Can someone explain below example on JS arrow function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

Below function is the "dispatch" is a parameter or a something else. It will be helpful if someone can describe the theory behind this. As well as the traditional way of writing below function.

```
export const incrementCount = () => dispatch => {
    return dispatch({ type: actionTypes.INCREMENT })
};
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47002774/what-does-dispatch-mean-do-and-why-is-it-used-when-we-have-then-and-cat

Comment: I need to know on how "dispatch" word behaves. NOT ON how redux works

Comment: do you ask what is an arrow function or what does dispatch or what is redux thunk? if it's not the first one, then I suggest you read *any* basic article on how redux works because what dispatch does is actually can be translated to what is the flow of redux.

Comment: `incrementCount` is a function which returns a function, this last function takes as input a function called `dispatch` and inside it executes this dispatch function and returns the result of this execution.

Comment: Please add framework tag and then change the title to a relevant question like "How does dispatch work in this code"

Answer (score 0):

In the code above `incrementCount` is a function returning a function that accepts `dispatch` as a parameter and  that returned function is returning a `dispatch` method

```
export const incrementCount () {
  return function(dispatch) {
      return dispatch({ type: actionTypes.INCREMENT })
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So this has been called by dispatch(incrementCount()). So can you explain how this works and how dispatch parameter is passed to the function that you have mentioned.

Comment: you are using`redux-thunk` as middleware. when `dispatch(incrementCount()` is called it is caught by `redux-thunk` instead of `redux` and the returned function taking  dispatch  as argument is also handled by `redux-thunk`.